# Magento create duplicate site script in php

Tags: backup

I am looking for a PHP script that can create a backup mirror of my store for development purposes. I have been looking around, but not found.

Reading this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server#old_server

There must be a way or someone has done it to make a **full site and DB copy**?

For example: A all in one copy script - or something like modman that gabs all it needs and creates and second site

Comment: Why not just use svn or git to copy your files to local development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a ready made script to make a development copy of a site and a database.
As a freelance Magento developer, I've worked in many teams and companies. Every one had their own development and deployment methodology.
Creating a development backup of a site would have been different under every circumstance, too.

That said, it almost never happened that someone would copy back code from a production site, except initially for an inherited project.
In that case, `rsync` worked well. In all other cases, only a DB dump of the production system was fetched into dev or testing, since the code only was deployed in the other direction.

```
dev > testing > staging > production
```

or a variation thereof.

One tool I'm aware of to make pulling a dump of the database into dev is [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#stripped-database-dump) with the `db:dump --strip="@stripped"` option.
It eliminates the (legal) issues related to copying customer and other sensitive data to development environments.

To summarize, I suggest:

- roll your own tool to initially copy code from production to development (check out rsync)
- after that, only move code from dev to production
- use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to fetch db dumps from live to testing